# Using a static constexpr in gtest typed test

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

```
template <typename T> class ClassA : public ::testing::Test {
public:
  ClassA() {}

  constexpr static uint ZERO = 0;
};

typedef ::testing::Types<ClassB, ClassC, ClassD> ParamTypes;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(ClassA, ParamTypes);

template <> constexpr uint ClassA<test::ClassB>::ZERO;
template <> constexpr uint ClassA<test::ClassC>::ZERO;
template <> constexpr uint ClassA<test::ClassD>::ZERO;

TYPED_TEST(ClassA, testSomething) { ASSERT_EQ(ClassA::ZERO, 0); } ??
TYPED_TEST(ClassA, testSomething) { ASSERT_EQ(this->ZERO, 0); } ??
```

What is the right way to use static constexpr inside typed test with google test?

Comment: I think both forms you presented are legitimate...

Comment: @W.F. they are not working

Comment: I thought that you ware asking if one can access static constexpr by `this->`. My guess is that it does not working as you pass to the test incomplete template... `ClassA` is templated and as such it should have got specialized to be interpreted as a complete type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always have more success with constexpr functions in these scenarios - no need to provide a separate definition.

Also, fixed a couple of typos:

```
template <typename T> class ClassA : public ::testing::Test {
public:
    ClassA() {}

    constexpr static uint ZERO() { return 0; }
};

struct ClassB {};
struct ClassC {};
struct ClassD {};


typedef ::testing::Types<ClassB, ClassC, ClassD> ParamTypes;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(ClassA, ParamTypes);


TYPED_TEST(ClassA, testSomething) { ASSERT_EQ(ClassA<TypeParam>::ZERO(), 0); }
TYPED_TEST(ClassA, testSomethingElse) { ASSERT_EQ(this->ZERO(), 0); }
```